# Android: How do I evenly space images in a ScrollView?

Tags: android, scrollview

I want to evenly space a vertical row of images in a ScrollView.

I'm telling my `LinearLayout` inside the `ScrollView` to `fill_parent`, but it's not, it's wrapping content.

Comment: maybe a ListView would be better for what you want?

Comment: Approach with vertical LinearLayout inside ScrollView is fine (both set to fill_parent). Should be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post your XML? Are you putting each ImageView in a separate LinearLayout or what? Just put all your ImageViews inside a vertical LinearLayout, and add:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

to all of them. That should do the trick.

EDIT: Wait, I'm confused. What are you trying to accomplish? Do you have a fixed size for your ScrollView?

Comment: I'm trying to get the images to space evenly when there is enough room vertically for them to all fit on screen without scrolling, so there is no extra space at the bottom.

Comment: How many images do you have? Is it going to vary? Don't forget your app is going to be used on multiple screen sizes and resolutions, so what may fit on a Droid X won't necessarily fit on a Droid Eris, and vice versa.